# Why will google+ auto backup not work on my wireless network?

Tags: backup, google-backup

It appears that my pictures will not back up to google+ **unless** I allow the sync service to use my mobile data and disable wireless.  However, when back on my wireless, syncing just locks up, saying "Backing up...1 left" forever.  I've tried the "sync now" option and it does not help.

I've got an HTC M8 and COX as my ISP.  Is there a port they might be blocking or something?  This is so obnoxious.